using momentjs to fetch data from backend
I am trying to fetch data from the backend that has the trip status set to "upcoming"
but I want to conditionally fetch it using my current time. It should only fetch data that is max 15 minutes ahead. I have tried implementing it but i doesnt seem to work :(
const fetchUpcomingTrips = () => {

    let upcomingApiData = getTripsData?.data['upcoming'];
    if (upcomingApiData) {
      const currentTime = moment().utc(true).format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ');
      const fifteenMinutesLater = moment().add(2, 'minutes');
  
      console.log(currentTime);
  
      // Filter trips that are 15 minutes away from the start time
      const upcomingTrips = upcomingApiData.filter(trip => {
        const rideStartTime = moment(trip?.ride_start_time);
       return rideStartTime.isBetween(currentTime, fifteenMinutesLater);
      });

      setUpcomingTrips(upcomingTrips);
    }
    
  };

this is how the date and time is set at the backend:
"ride_start_time": "2024-08-14T19:51:00Z"
it follows 24hr time and the timezone is UTC
I tried using momentjs and making sure my current time format matches the backend but it doesn't

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Use standard Date objects. Create a now object and then another one 15 minutes later. Compare against a date from a backend. Something like this:
const now = new Date()

const later = new Date()
later.setMinutes(later.getMinutes() + 15)

const date = new Date("2024-08-14T19:51:00Z") 

console.log(now < date && date < later)


Try this date format this might help you 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ'
And in the given function you are extracting time after 2 minutes increase it by 15 minutes.
